# Proving that x is a perfect square when $x=11 + 11\sqrt{11a^2+1}$ is an odd integer , provided that $a$ is rational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this question in a book of maths MCQs under the chapter "Numbers". No solution was provided within that book. I can't solve it no matter how hard I try. Please help me.

P.S. : This is my first question on stack exchange so if I made any mistake, please don't be too harsh.

Comment: I am confused. For $a=3$, we have $11+11\sqrt{11\cdot 3^2+1}=121$, and $3$ is not a perfect square. Please check the claim.

Comment: @peter I think their was a misprint in the book. Thanks! Is there a way to close this question?

Comment: You need some reputation (I think, but I am not sure) , but then you can delete the question. Do you already see a button with "delete" ?

Comment: @Peter I can't see any 'delete' button . Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem in the book is probably the following:

Prove that if $ a $ is an odd integer such that $ 11 + 11 \sqrt{11a^2 + 1} $ is rational, then $ 11 + 11 \sqrt{11a^2 + 1} $ is a perfect square.

This is indeed true. An integer which is a rational perfect square is an integer perfect square, so let $ k > 0 $ be such that $ k^2 = 11a^2 + 1 $. Our goal is to prove that $ 11(k+1) $ is a perfect square. To do this, we will show that the power of $ p $ in the prime factorization of $ k+1 $ for any prime $ p \neq 11 $ is even, and the power of $ 11 $ is odd.

We have $ 11a^2 = (k-1)(k+1) $, and since $ a $ is odd, the same is true for $ k-1, k+1 $. It follows that $ \gcd(k-1, k+1) = 1 $. If $ p \neq 11 $ is a prime dividing $ k+1 $, then the power of $ p $ in $ k+1 $ is its power in $ 11a^2 $; in other words, it is even. It follows that $ 11(k+1) $ is *almost* a perfect square - we are done if we show that $ k \equiv -1 \pmod{11} $. Standard theory of Pell equations yields that $ 10 + 3\sqrt{11} $ is a fundamental unit for $ \mathbf Z[\sqrt{11}] $, and we have that, defining

$$ (10 + 3 \sqrt{11})^n = a_n + b_n \sqrt{11} $$

we see that $ a_n $ is $ 2 $-periodic modulo $ 11 $, and $ b_n $ is $ 2 $-periodic modulo $ 2 $. It follows that if $ b_n $ is odd, then $ a_n $ is $ -1 $ modulo $ 11 $. This implies that $ k $ is $ -1 $ modulo $ 11 $ when $ a $ is odd, and since $ a $ is odd, we are done.

Comment: Hmm, I interpeted it as meaning.  If $a$ is rational and $11 + 11\sqrt{11a^2 + 1}$ is an odd integer prove $11 + 11\sqrt{11a^2 + 1}$ is a perfect square, (which I haven't bothered verifying) (and which is compatible with yours as $11 + 11\sqrt{11a^2 + 1}$ is odd integer only if a is (presuming a is rational) and vice versa).

Comment: @fleablood The two claims are equivalent, for the reason you stated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just saying my interpretation was different than yours.  $a$ needs to be rational else we can have $a = \sqrt{\frac{k^2/11^2 - 1}{11}}$ To get the expression equal to 11 + k for any number.  (more relevant in my mind than the expression being rational... and odd integer is more applicatable to the result than the a...) It was just an observation in interpretation.  But in this case it all tumbles out in the wash.

Comment: I believe this is what the intended problem was. I checked the book again and the question asked to prove a to be a perfect square so it was a misprint. I have edited the title. I am sorry for any confusion this may have caused.